# Cross domain data sharing in same browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to share/pass the data between different domains inside the browser?

Note:

- I can have a code control on all the data sharing domains.
- I can not predict how many domains can be opened inside the browser to share the data.

I have tried a solution with Window.postMessage() but it requires destination site origin.

Can anyone suggest the way if any?

Comment: Please share the code you are using, and the error messages you're facing

Comment: `postMessage` only works between parent/child windows, ie a popup window spawned from a parent, or an iframe. It cannot communicate between wholly separate window instances. If your case does not fall in to one of those, then direct communication between tab/window instances is not possible

Comment: @NicoHaase Let's say there are multiple domains abc1.com....abcX.com, few of them opened the browser. When I post any message it should go to all these domains which are opened in the browser. Code is not showing any error at the same time sending a message by the origin name is not possible at the time.

Comment: To do this purely client side is not possible. For it to work you'd need a complex system which sends a message from the client-side to the server of the *current* domain. Then you'd need another system, which is shared between *all* domains, to receive messages and send them to all other connected clients on those domains. I'd suggest SignalR for that.